# PyQt not displaying pixmap properly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm new to PyQt and I can't seem to quite work out all the kinks. For some reason, whenever I click the "play game" button, the image just doesn't appear. However, it does run the `InitUI`. Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong? (when It just loaded up the image initially, the image appeared.

**class Example(QMainWindow):**

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title = 'PyQt5 image - pythonspot.com'
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    central_widget = QWidget()
    self.chess = ChessWidget(central_widget)
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
    self.resize(900,900)
    self.center()
    self.setFixedSize(self.size())
    self.show()

def toggleMenu(self, state):

    if state:
        self.statusbar.show()
    else:
        self.statusbar.hide()

# def closeEvent(self, event):
#
#     reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
#                                  """Are you sure you want to quit?""", QMessageBox.Yes |
#                                  QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
#
#     if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
#         event.accept()
#     else:
#         event.ignore()

def center(self):

    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

**class ChessWidget(QFrame):**

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    qbtn = QPushButton('Play Game', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: qbtn.close())
    qbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.initUI())
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(qbtn)
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)
    self.setLayout(vbox)

def initUI(self):
     print("hi")
     pixmap = QPixmap("ChessBoard.jpg")
     lbl = QLabel(self)
     pixmap2 = pixmap.scaledToWidth(900)
     hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
     hbox.addStretch(1)
     hbox.addWidget(lbl)
     lbl.setPixmap(pixmap2) ` if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication([])
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_()) `
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a useful warning from Qt; if not, check that your test environment has a console active. The warning is:

`QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to ChessWidget "", which already has a layout`

This happens when you create the `QHBoxLayout` in `ChessWidget.initUI` and try to parent it to the `ChessWidget`. You have already set a `QVBoxLayout` on that widget.

A quick solution is to retain the name of your layout (`vbox` -> `self.vbox`), then in a click event remove the `QPushButton` from the layout and add the `ChessWidget`.

I understand you're just making small tests for learning purposes, but this design pattern with the `QPushButton` being permanently replaced might not be what you want. If you want the `QPushButton` and `ChessWidget` to occupy the same space, look at `QStackedWidget`. This will allow you to switch from one widget to the other as often as you like. This could be a useful approach if you want to hide the `ChessWidget` later when no game is active, for example.

Note that when you create your `QPushButton` and `QLabel`, it's unnecessary to parent them to the `ChessWidget` as they will be reparented to the layout when added.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.chess     = ChessWidget(central_widget)   
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.layV = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)               # +++
        self.layV.addWidget(self.chess)                       # +++

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('D:/_Qt/img/py-qt.png')) # web.png
        self.resize(440,440)    #(900,900)

class ChessWidget(QFrame): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        qbtn = QPushButton('Play Game', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: qbtn.close())
        qbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.initUI())

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()  
        self.hbox.addWidget(qbtn)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def initUI(self):
        print("hi")
        pixmap = QPixmap("D:/_Qt/img/pyqt.jpg") # ChessBoard.jpg
        lbl    = QLabel(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(lbl)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(400, 400, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))  # +++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    ex.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 image - pythonspot.com')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]